# Parameter passing ti inframe

Tags: php, parameter-passing

How do I get url multiple parameter and pass it on the iframe without spelling the parameter 1 by 1 on php

ex. URL www.sample.com/?parameter=parameter&parameter=parameter

And pass this parameter=parameter&parameter=parameter inside an inframe backend of the iframe src

original iframe

and the output is

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: The question is clear than water!

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will return the query string from URL.

```
$url = "www.sample.com/?parameter1=val1&parameter2=val2";
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

> Output
>
> parameter1=val1&parameter2=val2

Comment: Thanks mate.. I already got it and its working great with $get

Comment: Do you have sample?

Comment: The snippet is in my answer. Not sure what kind of sample do you need